# How to append HTML elements to DOM node using PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, domdocument

I'd like to append a span with a class into a div using PHP. But it doesn't work for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($toReplace);
$sourceDOMElement->appendChild($fragment);
$dom->saveXML();
```

Where $dom is the whole HTML document, $toReplace is the string of the span, like `<span class="dummy"></span>`, and $sourceDOMElement is the div I want to insert into.

I've read my current code here in SOF, but I have no idea why it doesn't work.
Can you help me please?

Comment: To answer this properly it would be useful to know what the source document is - is it the current page being viewed in the browser or is it a-n-other html page saved on the webserver or a remote file from another url?

Comment: I've tried something similar and it works as far as I can tell - though you may need `echo $dom->saveXML();` to see any output.